# Как сгенерировать массив 9х9 где будут ровно 9 единичек в рандомных местах?

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

Решил сделать игру в Сапёра, но столкнулся с проблемой при генераций поля. У меня должно создаётся массив который содержит число 1 (мина) и 0 (пустая клетка).

```js
const block = document.querySelector(".sapper");

  var bomb = 9, size = 9;

  var sapper = new Array(), repeat = 0;
  generateSapperArea();
  if(repeat < size){
    generateSapperArea();
  }

  function generateSapperArea(){
    for(let i = 0; i < size; i ++){
      sapper[i] = new Array();
      for(let j = 0; j < size; j ++){
        let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if(temp == 1) repeat ++;
        else temp = 0;

        if(repeat > size) temp = 0;
        sapper[i][j] = temp;
      }
    }
    return repeat;
  }
  console.log(sapper);
```

Как мне сгенерировать массив 9х9 где будут ровно 9 - 1 в рандомных местах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще вот так можно)

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  function createArea(size) {
    return Array(size)
      .fill([])
      .map(
        () => Array(size).fill(0)
      );
  }

  function fillBomb(area, bomb = 1) {
    let size = area.length;
    while (bomb) {
      let ceil = getRandomInt(0, size ** 2),
        j = ceil / size | 0,
        i = ceil % size;
      if (!area[j][i]) {
        area[j][i] = 1;
        bomb--;
      }
    }
    return area;
  }


  let area = createArea(9);
  area = fillBomb(area, 9);

  console.log(area);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я всё сделал, если кому-то интерестно я оставлю код нижу ^-^

```js
var bomb = 9,
  size = 9;
var sapper = new Array(),
  repeat = 0;
generateSapperArea();

function generateSapperArea() {
  while (repeat != 9) {
    repeat = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      sapper[i] = new Array();
      for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if (temp == 1) repeat++;

        if (repeat > size || temp != 1) temp = 0;

        sapper[i][j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(sapper);
```